# Using asyncore to create interactive sessions with client/server model

Tags: python, session, asynchronous, twisted, asyncore

I am attempting to create a program that allows many clients to connect to 1 server simultaneously. These connections should be interactive on the server side, meaning that I can send requests from the server to the client, after the client has connected.

The following asyncore example code simply replies back with an echo, I need instead of an echo a way to interactively access each session. Somehow background each connection until I decided to interact with it. If I have 100 sessions I would like to chose a particular one or choose all of them or a subset of them to send a command to. Also I am not 100% sure that the asyncore lib is the way to go here, any help is appreciated.

```
import asyncore
import socket

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.send(data)

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
            handler = EchoHandler(sock)

server = EchoServer('localhost', 8080)
asyncore.loop()
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, how you are going to use the sessions. Usually, a session is a concept to hold wider information about past communication between a client and server. But you are talking about addressing multiple session by one request, this is definitely something different (and unusual in terms of sessions). Your client/server request sounds like request/reply, but addressing multiple sessions sounds like tasking workers (it is not clear, what you would like to return as response).

Comment: Jan, what I am looking for is a way to (from server side) interact with all the agents. These agents will call back to one server on the same ip:port pair. On the server a log of all active connections should exist viable via some command, also a way to interact with them via s.send(). What I vision is, 100 agents call back to my server at any time and stay connected. I then come to my server hours later and type (list) and it gives me a list of active connections, then I chose to interact with 1 connection and send a dir request. The agent sends me the results.

Comment: I realize that s.listen() has the ability to backlog connections, is there a way to bring those connections into the forefront and backlog the active one and vice versa? this may be what I need.

Comment: I see, sessions are in role of connections. The request seems clear to me now. It is not trivial messaging task, but it shall be possible. I would propose small change - at the moment of `list` do not count live connections, but better ask clients to report, they are really alive. This would simplify the solution I have in my mind.

Comment: I was hoping to provide simple zmq based solution, but the whole experiment turned a bit too complex and I give up. There are too many difficulties around mainly due to rather complex messaging scenarios. Started with load balancing example from zeromq guide, then moved to asynchronous request reply and finally got lost in matching asynchronous requests and replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Twisted server:

```
import sys

from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.endpoints import serverFromString
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory

from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class HubConnection(LineReceiver, object):
    def __init__(self, hub):
        self.name = b'unknown'
        self.hub = hub

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.hub.append(self)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        words = line.split(" ", 1)
        if words[0] == b'identify':
            self.name = words[1]
        else:
            for connection in self.hub:
                connection.sendLine("<{}> {}".format(
                    self.name, line
                ).encode("utf-8"))

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.hub.remove(self)

def main(reactor, listen="tcp:4321"):
    hub = []
    endpoint = serverFromString(reactor, listen)
    endpoint.listen(Factory.forProtocol(lambda: HubConnection(hub)))
    return Deferred()

react(main, sys.argv[1:])
```

and command-line client:

```
import sys

from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.endpoints import clientFromString
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO

from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet.fdesc import setBlocking

class HubClient(LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self, name, output):
        self.name = name
        self.output = output

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.output.transport.write(line + b"\n")

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("identify {}".format(self.name).encode("utf-8"))

    def say(self, words):
        self.sendLine("say {}".format(words).encode("utf-8"))

class TerminalInput(LineReceiver, object):
    delimiter = "\n"
    hubClient = None
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.hubClient is None:
            self.output.transport.write("Connecting, please wait...\n")
        else:
            self.hubClient.sendLine(line)

@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor, name, connect="tcp:localhost:4321"):
    endpoint = clientFromString(reactor, connect)
    terminalInput = TerminalInput()
    StandardIO(terminalInput)
    setBlocking(0)
    hubClient = yield endpoint.connect(
        Factory.forProtocol(lambda: HubClient(name, terminalInput))
    )
    terminalInput.transport.write("Connecting...\n")
    terminalInput.hubClient = hubClient
    terminalInput.transport.write("Connected.\n")
    yield Deferred()

react(main, sys.argv[1:])
```

which implement a basic chat server.  Hopefully the code is fairly self-explanatory; you can run it to test with `python hub_server.py` in one terminal, `python hub_client.py alice` in a second and `python hub_client.py bob` in a third; then type into alice and bob's sessions and you can see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

## Review Requirements

You want

- remote calls in client/server manner
- probably using TCP communication
- using sessions in the call

It is not very clear, how you really want to use sessions, so I will consider, that session is just one of call parameters, which has some meaning on server as well client side and will skip implementing it.

## `zmq` as easy and reliable remote messaging platform

ZeroMQ is lightweight messaging platform, which does not require complex server infrastructure. It can handle many messaging patterns, following example showing request/reply pattern using multipart messages.

There are many alternatives, you can use simple messages encoded to some format like JSON and skip using multipart messages.

### `server.py`

```
import zmq

class ZmqServer(object):
    def __init__(self, url="tcp://*:5555"):
        context = zmq.Context()
        self.sock = context.socket(zmq.REP)
        self.sock.bind(url)
        self.go_on = False

    def echo(self, message, priority=None):
        priority = priority or "not urgent"
        msg = "Echo your {priority} message: '{message}'"
        return msg.format(**locals())

    def run(self):
        self.go_on = True
        while self.go_on:
            args = self.sock.recv_multipart()
            if 1 <= len(args) <= 2:
                code = "200"
                resp = self.echo(*args)
            else:
                code = "401"
                resp = "Bad request, 1-2 arguments expected."
            self.sock.send_multipart([code, resp])
    def stop(self):
        self.go_on = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ZmqServer().run()
```

### `client.py`

```
import zmq
import time

class ZmqClient(object):
    def __init__(self, url="tcp://localhost:5555"):
        context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        self.socket.connect(url)
    def call_echo(self, message, priority=None):
        args = [message]
        if priority:
            args.append(priority)
        self.socket.send_multipart(args)
        code, resp = self.socket.recv_multipart()
        assert code == "200"
        return resp
    def too_long_call(self, message, priority, extrapriority):
        args = [message, priority, extrapriority]
        self.socket.send_multipart(args)
        code, resp = self.socket.recv_multipart()
        assert code == "401"
        return resp


    def test_server(self):
        print "------------------"
        rqmsg = "Hi There"
        print "rqmsg", rqmsg
        print "response", self.call_echo(rqmsg)
        print "------------------"
        time.sleep(2)
        rqmsg = ["Hi There", "very URGENT"]
        print "rqmsg", rqmsg
        print "response", self.call_echo(*rqmsg)
        print "------------------"
        time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(2)
        rqmsg = []
        print "too_short_call"
        print "response", self.too_long_call("STOP", "VERY URGENT", "TOO URGENT")
        print "------------------"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ZmqClient().test_server()
```

### Play with the toy

Start the server:

```
$ python server.py
```

Now it runs and awaits requests.

Now start the client:

```
$ python client.py 
------------------
rqmsg Hi There
response Echo your not urgent message: 'Hi There'
------------------
rqmsg ['Hi There', 'very URGENT']
response Echo your very URGENT message: 'Hi There'
------------------
too_short_call
response Bad request, 1-2 arguments expected.
------------------
```

Now experiment a bit:

- start client first, then server
- stop the server during processing, restart later on
- start multiple clients

All these scenarios shall be handled by `zmq` without adding extra lines of Python code.

## Conclusions

ZeroMQ provides very convenient remote messaging solution, try counting lines of messaging related code and compare with any other solution, providing the same level of stability.

Sessions (which were part of OP) can be considered just extra parameter of the call. As we saw, multiple parameters are not a problem.

Maintaining sessions, different backends can be used, they could live in memory (for single server instance), in database, or in memcache or Redis. This answer does not elaborate further on sessions, as it is not much clear, what use is expected.